# c++ code: about sorted search test sample

Tags: c++

I am writing the the answer for a test sample given in testdome https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9880

The question is about sorted search:
Implement function countNumbers that accepts a sorted vector of integers and counts the number of vector elements that are less than the parameter lessThan.

For example, for vector v containing { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, SortedSearch::countNumbers(v, 4) should return 2 because there are two vector elements less than 4.

I modified code as below, but the test result tells there are two fails: 
1)Performance test when sortedVector contains lessThan: Time limit exceeded 
2)Performance test when sortedVector doesn't contain lessThan: Time limit exceeded

Can you help to update my code to fix the problem?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class SortedSearch
{
public:
    static int countNumbers(const std::vector<int>& sortedVector, int lessThan)
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (size_t i=0; i<sortedVector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (sortedVector[i]<lessThan)
            {
                a++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    std::cout << SortedSearch::countNumbers(v, 4);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact the data is sorted to find the answer in logarithmic time. The C++ standard library has an algorithm for this task.

Use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to find the first element greater or equal to your target value. Then call [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to return the count of elements from the start of the container to the location found in the previous step.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class SortedSearch
{
public:
    static int countNumbers(const std::vector<int>& sortedVector, int lessThan)
    {
        // get an iterator to the first element >= lessThan
        auto itr = std::lower_bound(std::begin(sortedVector), std::end(sortedVector), lessThan); // O(log n)

        // return the distance between two iterators
        return std::distance(std::begin(sortedVector), itr); // O(1)
    }
};
```

Comment: @Slava I could specify the namespace but they can be found by argument-dependent lookup (ADL). Maybe I'll edit the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks Blastfurnace, to my understanding, the question is asking to count how many vector members are less tan parameter lessThan. I could not understand how your code reach the result. Can you explain in details?

Comment: @LeiWang `std::lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element that is **not less than** (i.e. greater or equal to) the target value. The number of elements less than the target is the offset of the returned iterator and the beginning of the container. That's what the `std::distance` call returns.

Comment: @LeiWang Note that this algorithm has logarithmic runtime so it's effectively doing a binary search. I tested this code on the site you linked and it passes the tests.

Comment: thanks. How about 2nd element that is not less than the target value? Do I need to repeat use this method for whole vector members or only call the these function just once as you presented. Seems the std::distance only return the offset from the beginning to the first element which less than target...

Comment: @LeiWang The returned iterator points to the first value that is either greater than or equal to the target. The computed distance is the count you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot the vector is sorted. If the vector is not sorted like {1 6 7 2 9 4}, can you use the same method?

Comment: @LeiWang No, that algorithm requires the sequence to be ordered. If it is not fully sorted it must at lease be partitioned with all elements less than the target to appear before the elements greater than or equal to. If not sorted or partitioned you'll have to do a linear search.

Comment: Oh my god, your're a genius. It took a painful half an hour to solve it for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to use faster approach. Use binary_search to find the last element less than given one.

Comment: Does this answer refer to [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) in the standard library? That function returns a `bool` so I'm not sure how it's useful here.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the implementation is already in Wiki: Binary Search algorithm.
Look for explanation and implementation in "Procedure for finding the leftmost element".

Here is my answer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class SortedSearch
{
public:
    static int countNumbers(const std::vector<int>& sortedVector, int lessThan)
    {
        int lower, upper, middle;

        lower = 0;
        upper = sortedVector.size();

        // do a binary search
        while(lower < upper)
        {
            middle = (lower + upper) / 2;

            if (sortedVector[middle] < lessThan)
            {
                lower = middle + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                upper = middle;
            }
        } 

        return lower;
        //throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    std::cout << SortedSearch::countNumbers(v, 4);
}
#endif
```

You will get 4/4.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that the vector is sorted can help speed up the code by not looking at the whole vector.

```
If (sortedVector[i]>=lessthan)
{
     return a;
}
```

This will terminate your loop when you hit an element that is greater than the lessthan and will save you unnecessary iterations. For your given main, it'll only go through 2 iterations instead of 4.

While this doesn't specifically address the problems mentioned above, see if it gives you enough performance boost with the test cases to pass them. This'll also make your worst case performance O(n) instead of O(n) for every run

Comment: Thanks, But here the question requests counting the number of vector elements that are less than the parameter lessThan. So, I think it should go through 4 iterations and check every member's value.

Comment: The question says the vector is sorted (which I assume is in ascending order)